# Send e-mail with InlineImages

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, inline-images

I've created a script to send emails to a list of e.mail addresses with a PDF attachment. Now I want to "pimp it", adding a picture taken from Drive at the beginning of the email.

I found this method on Google Developers - [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)) - but it's not crystal clear to me on how it works.

This is the code I wrote so far, but it's not working. I keep reading only the text, without any picture. It should take the first 50 rows of a spreadsheet, send an email to the address in column 9 and update column 11 once done.

```js
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(source.getSheets()[2]);
 var row = 3
 var subject = "Subject";
 var imageId = DriveApp.getFileById("0B-OVYDHfkqhXOTF6aWVSSUtSbUE");
 var htmlText = "<img src = "cid:imageId" />  Dear Friend, <BR> <BR> Text";

 for (var i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
   var emailAddress = sheet.getRange(row + i, 9).getValue()
   var message = "Hi,\n \n" + "text";

   MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
     name: "Alternative Name",
     htmlbody: htmlText,
     attachments: [budgetPDF],
     inLineImages: imageId
   })

   sheet.getRange(row + i, 11).setValue("Sent");
```

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: this is covered right in the official sample for sending emails. other s.o. questions also cover this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get the blob of the file.

```
var imageId = DriveApp.getFileById("0B-OVYDHfkqhXOTF6aWVSSUtSbUE");
var imageIdBlob = imageId.getBlob();
var htmlText = "<img src = 'cid:imageIdBlob' />  Dear Friend, <BR> <BR> Text";
.....
.....
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
     name: "Alternative Name",
     htmlbody: htmlText,
     attachments: [budgetPDF],
     inLineImages: imageIdBlob
   })
```

As I don't know the format of the file you can also use [getAs()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getAs(String)).

Stéphane

Comment: Hi Stéphane, thanks for your input, but I already tried that. Unfortunately I get an error message saying that I'm missing the ; before the instruction on the var htmlText line...I really don't get it...Am I doing something wrong with the quotation marks?

Comment: @30331 that was a mismatched-quotes thing, fixed now.